# oracle add select statement in oracle bulk forall collect loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following plsql statement:

```
DECLARE
VPERIODID          VARCHAR2 (10);
vPROCSESSID        NUMBER;
VAUDITORID         NUMBER;

CURSOR c
IS
     SELECT *
      FROM view_cost_noabc
     WHERE OAUDITORID = 477 AND FL <> 'Ο' AND yearid < 2015
  ORDER BY ID;

TYPE nt_type IS TABLE OF c%ROWTYPE;

l_arr              nt_type;   
TYPE vPREVPERIODVALUE IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

vprev              vPREVPERIODVALUE;

dml_errors         EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
  SELECT fn_periodcurrent INTO vPERIODID FROM DUAL;
  SELECT fn_processcurrent INTO vPROCSESSID FROM DUAL;

OPEN c;

LOOP
   FETCH c
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_arr
   LIMIT 500;

   EXIT WHEN l_arr.COUNT = 0;

   BEGIN
      FOR r IN 1 .. l_arr.COUNT
      LOOP
        vprev (r).vPREVPERIODVALUE :=
           'SELECT NVL (SUM (CURRPERIODVALUE), 0)
              FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
             WHERE     APPOINTOFCAID = l_arr (r).ID
                   AND PROCESSID < vPROCSESSID
                   AND SUBSTR (PROCESSID, 5, 2) = 12
                   AND AUDITORID = 477';
      END LOOP;

     FORALL i IN 1 .. l_arr.COUNT
        INSERT INTO liquidationsdetails (....)
             VALUES (...);
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN DML_ERRORS
     THEN
        NULL;
  END;
  EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;   
CLOSE C;
COMMIT;
END;
```

I want to set the results using a select statement in oracle bulk forall collect loop to a array variable.
In the above code I receive [Error] Execution (60: 42): PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'NUMBER' PL/SQL: Statement ignored.

I prefer to use the SELECT SUM () statement in forall loop if is it possible.

Any idea?

Comment: Use into clause with out using '=' symbol.

Comment: Are you sure that you insert a **constant** string up to 500 times into a variable?

Comment: Also Tarun I change using into clause:
    SELECT NVL (SUM (CURRPERIODVALUE), 0) INTO vprev        (r).vPREVPERIODVALUE
                  FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
                 WHERE     APPOINTOFCAID = l_arr (r).ID
                       AND PROCESSID < vPROCSESSID
                       AND SUBSTR (PROCESSID, 5, 2) = 12
                       AND AUDITORID = 477;
[Error] Execution (60: 35): ORA-06550: PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'NUMBER'

Comment: Wernfried I need to insert a result of select  into String array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code in the question you're trying to assign a string to an element in a table of numbers; in the comments you've modified that to select a numeric value, But in both you've got the table element reference wrong; this:

```
INTO vprev (r).vPREVPERIODVALUE
```

should just be:

```
INTO vprev (r)
```

The `vPREVPERIODVALUE` is the type of `vprev` (and is `TABLE OF NUMBER`), so you don't refer to that type directly.

You also don't seem to be initialising or extending that collection before trying to assign values to its elements.

Doing a single select for each iteration of the cursor loop seems rather odd and inefficient anyway; you could do an outer join in the cursor instead, something like:

```
CURSOR c
IS
    SELECT vcn.ID, vcn.OAUDITORID,
             NVL (SUM (CURRPERIODVALUE), 0) AS PREVPERIODVALUE
      FROM view_cost_noabc vcn
 LEFT JOIN LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS ld
        ON ld.APPOINTOFCAID = vcn.ID
       AND ld.AUDITORID = vcn.OAUDITORID
       AND ld.PROCESSID < vPROCSESSID
       AND SUBSTR (ld.PROCESSID, 5, 2) = 12
     WHERE vcn.OAUDITORID = 477 AND vcn.FL <> 'Ο' AND vcn.yearid < 2015
  GROUP BY vcn.ID, vcn.OAUDITORID
  ORDER BY vcn.ID;
```

Then you don't need `vPREVPERIODVALUE`, `vprev` or your inner loop at all. You may need other columns from `view_cost_noabc` for your insert - if so add them to the select list and the group-by clause. You can then refer to `l_arr(i).PREVPERIODVALUE` to see the corresponding value, since that's still based on the cursor's rowtype; and I've used a left outer join because it looks (based on the `NVL`) like you won't always have matching records in `LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS`.

You haven't shown the table DDL, but since `vPROCSESSID` is declared as a number it's likely the `PROCESSID` is also a number - in which case using `substr` on it is strange - you're doing an implicit conversion to a string, and assuming the length is at least 7 digits. This may make sense for you and your data but just looks odd.

At the moment the `forall` insert is inside the inner loop which is not likely to be what you really intended; but if you lose the inner loop that problem will go away anyway.

Comment: Alex Poole I cant use inner join. Some records of view_cost_noabc I need to insert into LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS. I need to check in LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS if an indedified record is allready inserted, If yes I need to get the amount of old record and put it in a column previousvalue to the new inserting record.

Comment: @Giorgos - I've used a left outer join, not an inner join; I'm assuming (from the nvl) that you might not have any matching records in `liquidationdetails`.